# Differential Equation with Integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Determine the unique solution of:

$$y'+4y+5\int_0^x y\,dx = e^{-x},$$ given that $y(0)=0$.

[Hint: Take the derivative of both side of the given equation before you start solving.]

Please I need help to solve this undertermined coefficient problem. Please help me by step by step. I will rate you high surely. Thank you!!

Comment: I have attempted to fix the formatting to make it clearer. Please make sure I have not altered your intended meaning. also, be aware that $\int_0^xy\,dx$ does not make sense. Should it be $dy,$ perhaps? Something else? Maybe the limits of integration should be different?

Comment: well that is how it's written. and I guess it need to use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Write $z=\int_0^x ydy$, and then, you'll get a linear equation of $z$.

Comment: Isn't by FTC x replace y. the the equation look after Y"+4y'+5x =-e^(-x)

Comment: @user109041 in this case the FTC says $$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x y dx = y$$ More generally speaking the FTC says $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$$ Do you see why they are the same here?

Comment: y " + 4y ' + 5y = -e^(-x)

[r^2 + 4r + 5 = 0]
[quadratic formula gives r = -2 +/- i]
[general equation: y = (c1)e^(-2x)cos(x) + (c2)e^(-2x)sin(x) + Yp]

[Since g(x) = -e^(-x) let Yp = Ae^(-x)]
[derivatives:
Yp ' = -Ae^(-x)
Yp" = Ae^(-x)]

[plugging into diff eq:

Ae^(-x) - 4Ae^(-x) + 5Ae^(-x) = -e^(-x)]

[2Ae^(-x) = -e^(-x)]

[2A = -1]

[A = -1/2]

general solution:

[y = (c1)e^(-2x)cos(x) + (c2)e^(-2x)sin(x) + (-1/2)e^(-x)]
PLEASE TAKE A LOOK!!
Is it right way to go and how can I use the Initial condition ??

Answer (score 2):

If we take the derivative, $\dfrac{d}{dx}(y'+4y+5\int_0^x y\,dx = e^{-x})$, we have:

$$\tag 1 y''+4y'+5y = -e^{-x}$$

We now have a second order DEQ, so we need two initial conditions and only have one.

We can use the first IC to find the second one:

$$y'(0) + 4 y(0) + 5\int_0^0 y\,dx = e^{-0} \rightarrow y'(0) = 1$$

Now, we can use undetermined coefficients to find the homogeneous solution and guessing to find the particular solution.

For the homogeneous, we have:

$$m^2 + 4m + 5 = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = -2 \pm ~i$$

This gives a homogeneous solution of:

$$y_h(x) = e^{-2x} (c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x)$$

For the particular solution, we guess at a solution of $y_p = ae^{-x}$, substitute and solve for $a$, yielding:

$$y_p(x) = -\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-x}$$

Our solution is:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = e^{-2x} (c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x)-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-x}$$

Now, substitute in the two ICs and solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

**Spoiler**

> $y(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-2x}(\cos x + 3 \sin x - e^x)$

Comment: Great "process" piece!

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this equation by using the Laplace transform (if the hint is not only the choice). Let $Y(s)=\cal L\{(y(x)\}$. Then the Laplace transform of either side of the equation gives
$$sY(s)-y(0)+5\cal \{1*y\}=\frac{1}{s+1},$$ where  $1*y$ is the convolution of the functions $1$ and $y$, which is equal to $\frac{Y(s)}{s}$. Using this and the condition $y(0)=0$ in the equation we get $$\frac{s^2+5}{s}Y(s)=\frac{1}{s+1},$$ or $$Y(s)=\frac{s}{(s+1)(s^2+5)}=-\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}{s+1}+\frac{5}{6}.\frac{1}{s^2+5}+\frac{1}{6}.\frac{s}{s^2+5}.$$ The inverse Laplace transform yields that $y(x)=-\frac{1}{6}e^{-x}+\frac{1}{6\sqrt{5}}\sin \sqrt{5}x+\frac{1}{6}\cos\sqrt{5} x$.

Comment: You lost a constant and it affects the answer.

Comment: You are right Isaw it thanks